# Incorporate Angularjs in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

First let me explain that I have .NET programming background and I am new to Angularjs.

I have a MVC 5 application and I want to include a new section that is built with Angularjs as a Single Page Application.

So far I have a MVC 5 Controller with an Index action. In the Index.cshtml view is the SPA created with Angularjs which is using router module.
The Angular calls other pages that are in html format.

My problem is that html pages refer images like this:
`<img src="img/image.png">` but when the application is hosted not in the root folder the paths are incorrect.

I need to do it like this: `<img src="@Url.Content("~/img/image.png")">` to format the correct path for the images, but I cant do it in html pages.

Can you tell me how to convert them from .html to .cshtml to use the help of Razor? Also I need to know where is recommended to put those pages relatively to Index.cshtml in a standard MVC 5 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your AngularJs templates to be in .cshtml (Razor), you need to create partial actions for them. Create an action in your mvc controller and return the view as you would in normal MVC. The thing you need to take into account is that you need to set the Layout to `null` so you don't get the full Layout rendered when displaying these partial views. Then, in Angular you need to reference this actions via their full route.